# Program wont sum random elements from matrix array

Tags: c

everyone!

I create matrix with random elements:

```
static int array[10][10];
int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;

printf("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);


for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d ", rand() % 10);
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

And this is one function to sum row elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
    }

    printf("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", i, sum);
    sum = 0;

}
```

My problem is that program wont to sum it properly, program just print `0` for result.
Also, when I add manual elements, program works fine, but wont with random numbers.

Someone to help me? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't entered any values into your array. Try doing that before you add them together.

Comment: Program print me elements, just wont sum them.

Comment: That's because you are only using `printf`—that prints the random numbers, but it doesn't save them anywhere. You need to assign them to the array with something like `array[i][j] = value`.

Comment: add `array[i][j] = 42;` inside the first loops.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually assigned the values to the array; you're just printing them.

```
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        int num = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", num);
        array[i][j] = num;
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

is probably what you want.

Also the array has space for only 10 x 10 elements. So you need to validate that the inputs for `m` and `n` do not exceed that limit.

Comment: Yeah thats it, i understand now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `int` type in C is `0`. Because you do not enter the value to array, so all of values of this array are equal to `0`. So `sum = 0` after all calculations.

Try to initialize values for this array. For example, in the first for loop (the for loop content `printf` with `rand()` function):

```
array[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

OR

```
array[i][j] = 1; // or whatever you want
```

Comment: Thank you, but why my program now print same elements, no matter how many time I repeat it program print me same elements

Comment: You have to seed the random number generator, so add `srand ( time(NULL) );`  out of for loop before using `rand()`